# Split comma separated entries to rows

Tags: db2, csv, db2-luw, db2-9.7

I have a table like this:

```
|   ID   |  OtherID  | Data
+--------+-----------+---------------------------
|  5059  |   73831   | 5103,5107
|  5059  |   73941   | 5103,5104,5107
|  5059  |   73974   | 5103,5106,5107,5108
```

And the result should return individual rows, like this:

```
|   ID   |  OtherID  | Data
+--------+-----------+--------------------------
|  5059  |   73831   | 5103
|  5059  |   73831   | 5107
|  5059  |   73941   | 5103
|  5059  |   73941   | 5104
|  5059  |   73941   | 5107
|  5059  |   73974   | 5103
|  5059  |   73974   | 5106
|  5059  |   73974   | 5107
|  5059  |   73974   | 5108
```

Basically, I need to split my data at the comma into individual rows.

The result will be stored in a temporary table (Like: `ID, OtherID, NewID`).

My version of DB2 is 9.7

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367069/how-to-transform-comma-separated-column-into-multiples-rows-in-db2/24368140#24368140

Comment: @mustaccio, might not hurt to copy that answer over here.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a solution for your data set based on some work that I was doing and some modifications to the solution posted by [Serge Rielau and Rick Swagerman on IBM's developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/how_to_split_a_string_into_a_set_of_rows_anti_listagg12?lang=en).

**Data Setup queries:**

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE sample_data (id INTEGER, otherid integer, data VARCHAR(255)) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT preserve rows NOT logged;
INSERT INTO session.sample_data SELECT 5059, 73831, '5103,5107' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
INSERT INTO session.sample_data SELECT 5059, 73941, '5103,5104,5107' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
INSERT INTO session.sample_data SELECT 5059, 73974, '5103,5106,5107,5108' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

**Solution Select Query:**

```
WITH
split_data AS
(
    SELECT
        id as group_by_1,
        otherid as group_by_2,
        data AS split_string,
        ','  AS split
    FROM
        session.sample_data
)
,
rec
(
    group_by_1,
    group_by_2,
    split_string,
    split,
    row_num,
    column_value,
    pos
) AS
(
    SELECT
        group_by_1,
        group_by_2,
        split_string,
        split,
        1,
        VARCHAR(SUBSTR(split_string, 1, DECODE(INSTR(split_string, split, 1), 0, LENGTH(split_string), INSTR(split_string, split, 1) - 1)), 255),
        INSTR(split_string, split, 1) + LENGTH(split)
    FROM
        split_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        group_by_1,
        group_by_2,
        split_string,
        split,
        row_num + 1,
        VARCHAR(SUBSTR(split_string, pos, DECODE(INSTR(split_string, split, pos), 0, LENGTH(split_string) - pos + 1, INSTR(split_string, split, pos) - pos)), 255),
        INSTR(split_string, split, pos) + LENGTH(split)
    FROM
        rec
    WHERE
        row_num < 30000
    AND pos > LENGTH(split)
)
SELECT
    group_by_1 as id,
    group_by_2 as otherid,
    column_value AS data
FROM
    rec
ORDER BY
    group_by_1,
    group_by_2,
    row_num;
```

**Results:**

```
ID  OTHERID DATA
5059    73831   5103
5059    73831   5107
5059    73941   5103
5059    73941   5104
5059    73941   5107
5059    73974   5103
5059    73974   5106
5059    73974   5107
5059    73974   5108
```

**Comments:**

The solution select query can be modified to fit your specific result needs by including as many GROUP_BY_X rows (O to many) in the REC table definition and matching rows in the two unioned sub-selects.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I had a recent project where I needed to accomplish something similar with a simpler solution and thought I should share this approach using XMLTABLE instead of recursive SQL.

#### Data Setup

Data setup is the same as in Jeff Rudnick's answer.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.sample_data (
    ID        INTEGER,
    OtherId   INTEGER,
    Data      VARCHAR(255)
    )
    WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
INSERT INTO session.sample_data values
    (5059, 73831, '5103,5107'),
    (5059, 73941, '5103,5104,5107'),
    (5059, 73974, '5103,5106,5107,5108');
```

#### Solution

```
SELECT sd.ID, sd.OtherId, si.item as NewId
  from session.sample_data sd
      ,XMLTABLE('$doc/items/item'
          PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT CAST('<items><item><value>'||replace(sd.Data,',','</value></item><item><value>')||'</value></item></items>' as CLOB)) as "doc"
          COLUMNS
          ITEM VARCHAR(255) PATH 'value'
      ) si
;
```

#### Results

```
ID     OTHERID   NEWID
5059   73831     5103
5059   73831     5107
5059   73941     5103
5059   73941     5104
5059   73941     5107
5059   73974     5103
5059   73974     5106
5059   73974     5107
5059   73974     5108
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers I think I'd point out that, when applied to non-trivial amounts of data, this approach might perform poorly, because parsing XML is inherently much slower than simple string operations.

Comment: I wonder how it compares to recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You may even shorten the last solution via XMLTABLE() 
by getting rid of the value tag:

```
SELECT sd.ID, sd.OtherId, si.item as NewId
  from session.sample_data sd
      ,XMLTABLE('$doc/items/item'
          PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT CAST(   '<items><item>'
                                         || replace(sd.Data , ',' , '</item><item>')
                                         || '</item></items>' as CLOB
                                        )
                           ) as "doc"
          COLUMNS
          ITEM VARCHAR(255) PATH '.'
      ) si ;
```